# Why does this silverlight code get a "catastrophic failure" when reading a BitmapImage out of IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage, bitmapimage

In a **Silverlight** app, I save a **Bitmap** like this:

```
public static void SaveBitmapImageToIsolatedStorageFile(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e, string fileName)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, isf))
        {
            Int64 imgLen = (Int64)e.Result.Length;
            byte[] b = new byte[imgLen];
            e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
            isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            isfs.Flush();
            isfs.Close();
            isf.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and **read** it back out like this:

```
public static BitmapImage LoadBitmapImageFromIsolatedStorageFile(string fileName)
{
    string text = String.Empty;

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!isf.FileExists(fileName))
            return null;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(isoStream);
                return bitmapImage; // "Catastrophic Failure: HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this always gives me a "**Catastrophic Failure: HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))**" error.

I've seen this error before when I tried to read a **png file** off a server which was actually a **text file**, so I assume the Bitmap is not being saved correctly, I [got the code here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=234).

**Can anyone see how the BitmapImage is not being saved correctly? Or why it would be giving me this error?**

## Update:

**When the BitmapImage is created, I see that the array of bytes that gets written is 1876 bytes long and they are all 0. Why would that be?**

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work but am unclear exactly why. I was calling SaveBitmapImageToIsolatedStorageFile(...) **after** this code:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(e.Result);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmapImage;
```

If I call it **before** that code, then it works.

Apparently SetSource() zeroes out the bytes in **e.Result** but keeps the length?

Comment: SetSource will read from the stream (e.Result), so the position in the stream will change, but the length will not.  I'm not sure if you are allowed to seek on the result stream, but you could use a MemoryStream as a buffer and seek back to the beginning to use the data again.